# Subset Sum Problem

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions

I recently saw the following problem, and I'm exploring the possibility of generalising  it in various directions.

Consider a collection of $n$ cubic blocks with side lengths $1,2,\ldots,n$. It is easy to find conditions on $n$ such that the collection can be split into two (or more) sub-collections so that that each sub-collection can be stacked to create a tower of the same height. I won't give away how to do this in case you want to explore this relatively straightforward problem yourself.

In fact, you can split the collection in two so that both sub-collections are the same surface area. This is harder, but possible. Again, I won't give away the approach in case you want to think about this yourself.

I've struck problems when considering two (or more) sub-collections that have the same total volume. I suspect that this can be never done, but I'm not sure of the best way to prove this. I've tried exploring the generating function,

$$(1+x^{1^3})(1+x^{2^3})\cdots(1+x^{n^3}).$$

However, while this seems good at showing that something can't be done, it appears to be less useful in proving that it can never be done. Basically, I'd have to show that the coefficient of $x^{n^2(n+1)^2/8}$ is always zero. Does anyone know a nice strategy for showing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some counterexamples, for example:

$3^3 + 5^3 + 6^3 + 7^3 + 10^3 + 11^3 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 4^3 + 8^3 + 9^3 + 12^3 = 3042$

$3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 + 6^3 + 8^3 + 10^3 + 11^3 + 12^3 + 13^3 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 7^3 + 9^3 + 14^3 + 15^3 = 7200$

$1^3 + 2^3 + 4^3 + 7^3 + 8^3 + 11^3 + 13^3 + 14^3 = 3^3 + 5^3 + 6^3 + 9^3 + 10^3 + 12^3 + 15^3 = 7200$

Comment: Nice. I clearly didn't look hard enough! Now I just need to figure out some conditions on $n$ that guarantee that this works. Your counterexamples could provide some clues. Many thanks.

Comment: Why are there so many solutions for $n=20$ but only $0$ or $1$ or $2$ for smaller $n$?

Comment: Right. So there's a good open problem. How many solution are there for a given $n$. But I guess that means trying to find the coefficient of that generating function. Did you find your counterexamples numerically?

Comment: Ok. New conjecture. It can always be done when $n=4k$ or $n=4k+3$, and never done if $n=4k+2$ or $n=4k+3$. The "never done" part is easy. I'll have a think about the first part when I get a moment. That shouldn't be too hard. Certainly this result isn't anywhere near as strong as finding exactly how many ways it can be done though...